# SQL for finding composite key elements with same field

Tags: query

I have a table with a composite key `(a,b)` wherein I want to return the first key and the count of the second key that have the exact same set. For example if we have:

```
 a | b
-------
01 | 2
01 | 3
02 | 1
02 | 2
02 | 3
03 | 2
04 | 2
04 | 3
```

Since 01 and 04 have the same second column `(2,3)` and the others have none we get:

```
01 | 1
02 | 0
03 | 0
04 | 1
```

This should apply to any set of composite keys `(a,b)` and not its not just inclusion but equality we're looking for.

Comment: which database?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it's a question from a textbook where they use basic sql.